# Best way to tell if NServiceBus is still processing?

Tags: nservicebus

I am looking for a way to tell if NSB is still processing a message, including any internally triggered events/commands, so that within automated tests I can wait until a process has completed before moving on to the next step.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have auditing turned on, check to see when the message you sent the endpoint-under-test appears in the audit queue. When the message is in the audit queue, you can know that it has been successfully processed by the endpoint.

Comment: What about any events that were published as part of processing that message?  My understanding was that the original message would be put in the audit queue once it had processed and guaranteed that any events published were done so without error. That it wouldn't encapsulate the processing of any 'sub messages'.

Comment: That's correct - if the message is audited, then any events that were published by the handler would have been successful. It is important to not that that does NOT mean that those events were processed - just that the messages were queued up successfully.

Comment: That's my problem though, I want a way of knowing that the original message and any events/commands that it has published/sent have completed.  That the entire process/conversation has completed.

Comment: Then you'd need to look to see that all the other messages that make up the process are audited as well.